# Measurable function with respect to $\sigma - $ algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X = \{ A \subset R: A$ is a countable set or $A^c$ is countable set $\}$  We know $X$ is a $\sigma - $ algebra . Find an example of measurable function with respect to $M$ (i.e. the function whose preimage of an open set is in $X$). Characterize such function in general.

**My idea:**
First $f(x) = c $ constant function, but this function is not accepted.
Second, we got to have a function that somehow include $Q$ since we know $Q$ is countable, but this is as far i can get.

Any example of the functions that will satisfy the above problem? Thanks

Comment: The constant function $f=c$ is measurable. The preimage of any open interval will be $\emptyset$ or $\mathbb R$, which are both measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then the pre-image of any interval either consists of $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}^c$, $\varnothing$ or $\mathbb{R}$, so it is indeed measurable with respect to the desired set.

Comment: I can use characteristic function $f(x) = \chi_{Q} (x) $ correct?

Comment: Yeap! Infact any sum and multiple of characteristic functions of countable sets works to!

Comment: just to make sure i understand correct: $f^{-1}(\infty, c)$ where $c \leq 0$ is $\varnothing$, $f^{-1}(-\infty, c)$ where $c \geq 1$ is $Q$ and $f^{-1}(-\infty, c)$ where $0 <c  <1$ is $Q^c$. Am i missing something?

Comment: Should be $f^{-1}(-\infty, c)=\mathbb{R}$ for $c\ge 1$, but otherwise, I think your good!

Comment: Ya, I think I typed it wrong, but which case will be $Q$ then?

Comment: $f^{-1}(c, \infty)$ for $1\le c>0$